# web service best practice - server timeout longer than http client timeout

Tags: web-services, rest, hbase

I am trying to build a web service on top of hbase, so the code looks roughly like:

```
@GET
@Path("/blabla")
@Override
public List<String> getEvents($$$params$$$) {
    ......
    //calling hbase query the events
    ......
}
```

When Hbase service is down, the hbase Java API keeps retrying to connect to Hbase region server util eventually it times out and throws a RT Exception:

```
NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for event,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
```

The logic has no problem, my issue here is that the HttpClient times out way before hbase times out the retries. Then my web service API consumer gets no response, ugly.

**Question -**

What's the best practice here if you have server's timeout potentially longer than the http connection itself? How to have the web service respond to client gracefully in this case?

Answer (score 1):

set the cashing for you scan object to some reasonable value. another thing, since you are using a web service to show the results to your users, i am assuming that you must be showing only a few rows(or records) at a time. you can use Hbase PageFilter so that you get only a specified no of rows each time and don't have to wait to get all the rows in one shot.